# BCP Command "Login Timeout Expired"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

First time I have ever used BCP and I am using it to try and retrieve the full "URL" column data in my huge database. I keep receiving the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\Temp\DBDUMP>bcp "SELECT URL FROM Rocket.dbo.siteentry WHERE Content LIKE ''" queryout C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\Temp\DBDUMP\Output.txt -S rocketserver -T -U REMOVED -P REMOVED
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 67
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67].
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 67
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
```

I am using the following command with the passwords & server just replaced with "helloworld"

```
bcp "SELECT [URL] FROM [dbo].[siteentry] WHERE [Content] LIKE ''" queryout  Output.txt -S helloworld.database.windows.net,1433 -T -d Rocket -U rocketserver@rocketserver -P helloworld -c
```

Comment: I seems like `rocketserver` doens't have a default instance. Perhaps the instance you are trying to connect is a named instance?

Comment: You can connect using SSMS, right? What is the output of ´SELECT @@SERVERNAME´ statement.

Comment: you should not use -T and -U at the same time. -T means trusted connection. If both are present -T takes precedence. This problem will manifest after you solve the problem you have now.